# How to interpret the high number of upvotes on Git questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

While making myself familiar with Git I see questions with thousands of upvotes, which is much more than I previously saw on Stack Overflow, e.g.

- 14500 upvotes, 4900 stars [How do I undo the last commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-last-commits-in-git?rq=1)
- 10800 upvotes, 3600 stars, [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)
- 7600 upvotes, 2800 stars, [How to modify existing, unpushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits?rq=1)
- 6100 upvotes, 1100 stars, [How to undo git add before commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-to-undo-git-add-before-commit)
- 4700 upvotes, 2300 stars, [How to revert to a previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Compare that to the highest voted SVN question [How to migrate SVN repository to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository) (1200 votes, 680 stars), which might only have so many upvotes because it is Git related.

I was wondering why this is the case and I'm uncertain what reasons contribute to such a demand.

I currently see the following reasons:

- Git is very popular on Linux, through GitHub and is also used companies. It's the tremendous amount of users that explain the high interest.
- I personally find Git pretty puzzling. It's not so self explaining. If thousands of other users have similar problems understanding Git, we could conclude that the concept or implementation is crappy and there might be an easier way.
- Git benefits from the timely presence of Stack Overflow. Other tools have been there before Stack Overflow became popular and questions have been answered on different platforms.

Are there other reasons that I'm not aware of? How's the relationship between the above reasons, which one weighs more?

Comment: Another interesting thing to note aswell 

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all,all&geo=,&q=%2Fm%2F05vqwg,svn

Comment: I'm guessing it's a combination of your first reason - the overall high popularity of git - and the fact that all of those linked question essentially come down to *"I've made a mistake (commited too quickly, added the wrong stuff...) - how do I fix it?"*. These aren't scenarios that happen regularly so it's probable that you've forgotten how exactly to go about it and additionally - even if you're 90% sure how to do it - since you're trying to fix a mistake you'll probably want to really make sure you don't accidentally make another mistake as well that ends up making everything worse.

Comment: It's because of the overwhelming relief and gratitude at finding a correct answer for whichever git problem they've blundered into this time.  I use git command line daily and know it well, but would still upvote those questions thousands of times if I could.

Comment: @garfbradaz that's an interesting graph? Any clue on why China is still more supportive of SVN?

Comment: @Keiwan of course for most other technologies covered by SO the answer to "I've made a mistake, how do I fix it" is "just roll back to an earlier commit in git" :D

Comment: @fedorqui Or indeed, why does **anyone** have any interest in SVN at all...?

Comment: @Keiwan _"I've made a mistake [...]. These **aren't scenarios that happen regularly**"_ - sounds like Linus' main design flaw with Git: users _aren't_ perfect despite what he thinks, and programmers are users after all.

Comment: It's probably also because many visitors to questions in language tags are one-time visitors that come from Google but don't have an account. Those are new developers or people who don't write code for a living. They don't know how to vote, or don't want to make an account. But in order to have a git problem, you need to be using git. Lots of new devs don't use version control, so we can assume that you're already at least a bit experienced. For those, the likelihood to have an SO account is way higher. Those who do, vote on the answers, and that yields more votes.

Comment: For me it all boils down to option #2 you give. 'git' had (sometimes sill has)  a lot of unclarity in how to do things, inconsistency and doing things comparable, but quite unlike, every other (D)VCS.

Comment: Now watch as this meta post gets thousands of upvotes...

Comment: Pretty much entirely popularity would be my guess. I have just as much trouble with every VCS, but don’t mind because I never need to use them…

Comment: And in these cases is that I remember why I'll always prefer TFS vs GIT. Needing a CLI for a simple sync is beyond ridiculous. (And I have used GIT in the past)

Comment: Could also be that Git is less intuitive than its counterparts, hence more confusion and more hits in these questions. I, for one, had to google much more Git stuff than Mercurial stuff.

Comment: git's awesome, but it can be hard to get past the basic use cases.  there's often a way though - using complex command line wizardry.   and you are usually very relieved and happy to see someone else has spelled it out for you!!!  that's why i tend to upvote any good git Q&A couple.  very good and popular source control, but the API, while efficient and coherent, is complex.  haha, @JK said the same already.

Comment: Have you seen the amount of votes on java questions/answers? Yep. And there are way more users that use git

Comment: This question may end up in a war between SVN and GIT users, having TFS users sit by the side enjoying a drink.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor when things are popular and hard, they tend to attract upvotes

Comment: Another example IMO is `git reset HEAD~` (The answer to the top-voted git question), compare this to `hg rollback` in mercurial - which is damn easy to remember (but yes, limited to a single commit)

Comment: git is more popular and has a has a larger userbase, especially newbies getting started on it.

Comment: Compare that to the highest voted System-Verilog question [How to interpret blocking vs non blocking assignments in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog) 21 votes, 8 stars.

Comment: Git is integrated in newer versions of Visual Studio around 2013, which might have helped. I have never had need for command line Git thanks to the Sync in the Visual Studio GitHub extension.

Comment: Git is powerful but also rather complicated to use which results in some high traffic questions for SO. Basically these questions help repairing the deficits of git's UX experience. The high number of votes mean that SO is doing something useful here.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Personally, I think it's a combination of

- git's popularity (it is by far the most popular version control system nowadays)
- git's cryptic commands (what I like to call user-unfriendlyness)

e.g. compare the following commands to throw away your local modifications to a given file:

```
   # svn
   svn revert filename

   # hg
   hg revert filename

   # git
   git checkout -- filename
```

The first two are easy to remember, whereas the third one quite often requires googling - therefore more hits on the git questions on SO, and therefore more upvotes.

Another example is `hg incoming` vs `git <multiple commands that I am too lazy to look up right now>`.

My point being: questions for other VCS don't get as many upvotes because there's no need for people to ask these questions / search for them in the first place.

Comment: It's not about unfriendlyness, it's a way more complex tools for purpose to do things more complex than it is possible with SVN. Which is why commands are more complex.

Comment: @Walfrat I disagree. hg fulfills the same purpose as git and is way more user-friendly.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I in turn disagree. I like git way more, find its separaction of code, branches and the actual control it gives you is *way* better than hg. That is what user-friendly means for me, actual peace of mind in development.

Comment: By the way this answer is simply wrong (about the git command) it's really just `git checkout filename`. How is that harder to remember? I honestly think it's just about which tool you started with. Since I've been forced to use hg, I've been googling all the commands same I did when starting with git.

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier. I always use the -- version for revert. Probably learned it from SO. There are cases where -- is required, so git is not so simple after all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561142/difference-between-git-checkout-filename-and-git-checkout-filename

Comment: @anneb There are edge cases to hg revert as well, that make it "not so simple after all"... Most commands can be made more complicated when going after all cases, be it in mercurial or git. The other one were presenting the simplest case, there are no reason for the git one not to do it.

Comment: There is an important difference for --: git checkout <name> checks out the branch <name>. git checkout -- <name> checks out the index version of the file <name>.

Comment: Yes... do you often have files named `feature/PRJ-237-reduce-clutter` or branches named `manifest.json`? And, as I said, there are such important differences in the behavior of most functions... why you would stay stuck on the git one and not the other ones I don't understand.

Comment: Anyway, I don't care to fight over this, use whatever you prefer, my point is that saying that `git checkout -- filename`, or simply `git checkout filename` is more complicated to remember than `hg revert filename` is anything but fair, if not downright fallacious. The example about `hg incoming` is better, I guess, even though I actually never had a similar use case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion This is a good post to compare and choose

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: Mercurial is a VCS. Git was designed more as a VCS workflow construction kit than a finished VCS. In the beginning, it was envisioned that Git would only provide the low-level infrastructure (roughly on the same level of abstraction as a filesystem, except with history). This view has changed, and Git now ships with lots of high-level commands and features as well, but the low-level is still exposed, and it allows third parties to develop their own VCS workflows and tools on top of Git, e.g. Git Flow, Git-LFS and co. As such, Git may *look* more complex, but generally, if you …

Comment: … only work at a high level of abstraction, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, Fossil, Veracity, etc. have similar complexity, I find. In Mercurial the difference is more noticeable, because the low-level abstractions are not exposed to the casual user, they are only exposed as Python APIs, whereas in Git, the low-level abstractions are exposed as shell commands instead of APIs and thus "pollute" the namespace that is exposed to the casual user (binaries, man pages, etc.)

Comment: having gotten used to git (and having come from hg) `hg revert` is just wrong. What if I want to revert something 5 commits back? `git revert` does that. It's actually a universal revert. `hg revert` is arguably misnamed since it only deals with changes not yet checked in. I agree that `hg` was simpler than `git` but the workflow git encourages is far more powerful than hg's default workflow.

Comment: `git checkout -- filename` is also a bad example because `git status` reminds everybody that this is how to discard some changes in the working directory. And even thinking about such a revert without first looking at the `status` is a bit of a strange workflow.

Comment: Of course doing a `git status` before undoing changes is sensible. But I don't want to read the 10+ lines of `git status` just to know that I need to do `git checkout -- filename` to get rid of my local modifications.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier `git checkout filename` without `--` might work, but git itself recommends adding the `--` when you do a `git status`. 

Anyway, let's agree to disagree: for me, git's command line interface is quite confusing whereas obviously others find it straightforward.

Answer (score 62):

Some programmers use C#, others Java, others Python. Almost all of them use git.

Comment: Simple answer, but honestly true. I think even if git was more user friendly, it'd still have huge number of upvotes on questions.

Comment: doesn't explain the difference with SVN though..

Comment: Yes it explains well : there is about three or four GIT users for one S.V.N user right now in the world

Comment: @AntoinePelletier your statistic seem a bit off when compared to [another question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136079/are-there-any-statistics-that-show-the-popularity-of-git-versus-svn)

Comment: @JGreenwell A bit off you say ? It could almost be sarcastic. But i don't know where this feeling comes from : I feel like everyone is just talking about GIT and everyone uses it, it's completly overwhelming, and then you showed me this link... Could it be S.V.N users are more subtile ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Or they just don't want the "old techys" free bashing. My company currently use SVN, and it has absolutely no need to move to git. SVN does what we want it to do, we know how to administer it and use it. I do use recent technologies and unless we have a very reason to move to git (like really need what git provide that svn don't) I won't recommand to move from it.

Comment: If you listen the net, you would feel the vital necessity to use the latest, yet not mature and stable technologies, Java is totally outdated, Javascript server-side rules, .... People just talk about what it's new and change more that what it's already there for a long time, even if it doesn't add any value.

Comment: @JGreenwell Just to point out, that question/answer refers to repositories not users. It also doesn't take into account whether those repositories are still active.

Comment: @Walfrat good luck finding good developers willing to work with SVN. When I'm interviewing and see a dev with no git experience I give a big minus. Devs want to learn the newer tech so that they value more on the job market.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga note that i already worked a little with git. I'm just saying that switching from an existing svn to git when there will be no added value is not worth. And I have yet to met a developer that refuse a job because of SVN... Furthermore, newer technologies aren't always values more on the jobs market. See https://medium.com/@ChallengeRocket/top-10-of-programming-languages-with-the-highest-salaries-in-2017-4390f468256e AND https://www.techworm.net/2016/06/15-highest-paying-programming-languages-2016.html

Comment: @Walfrat migrating to git is easy. I think it is a small price to pay to make your company more attractive to young devs.

Comment: "small" ? don't be so sure, forming everyone to git has a cost, and I can tell you that this won't be easy for some of our devs here. And I am young and I don't really like devs that are only attracted to something because it's new. That's how you end up with tons of project use tons of different technologies that none master.

Comment: @Walfrat you're absolutely right. For an individual the switch is "easy", just adopt a slightly different workflow and keep a cheat sheet of "how I did it in SVN and how I do it in git" commands. I made the switch in under a day. Switching over entire teams + projects + workstations however, that requires a bit more orchestration.

Comment: @DBS That is entirely true, but those were the only statistics I could find (while searching with a headcold and only so much focus I admit). If you or someone else finds a better estimation of users (or at least active repositories) I would encourage you to combine the statistics into a new post.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier SVN users could be more "subtile" or (as was my case when using SVN over Git) they could just have more people knowledgeable about SVN. When I had a Git issue, I found my path was search official docs, search SO, then ask a question if not found, and finally ask a co-worker so I wasn't seen as not "knowing Git". When working with SVN it was search docs, search SO, then ask a co-worker cause it was just a tool and I would learn as I went (I also learned these systems faster this way). Note ClaudiuCreanga's attitude on Git as an example as it is the common one I've encountered.

Comment: OK, so it's more of being GIT the new technology that everyone has to use, and we should be ashamed not to know it, even with the puzzling commands. Versus S.V.N was there before, so it's considered the old unpleasant one to work with, but still a lot of company rely on it because it works whatever it's new or not. They each have their pros and cons to me... So i don't know why the big GIT attitude.

Comment: The thing is, SVN is so bad it's not even funny. Once you start using something like [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)  you'll never go back.

Comment: And I totally disagree with the notion that a big company "has no need to move from SVN." That's absurd and the worse part is obtuse. Big companies *need* to move to a distributed versioning system. Not doing so reeks of ignorance. Sorry for being blunt but it's like advocating staying with punch cards instead of start using terminals.

Answer (score 25):

Your second reason:

> I personally find Git pretty puzzling. It's not so self explaining

has been documented in more than one academic study:

[What's wrong with Git? A conceptual design analysis](https://spderosso.github.io/onward13.pdf)

[Purposes, Concepts, Misfits, and a Redesign of Git](https://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/106271)

From the abstract of the first paper:

> Despite its widespread adoption,
>   Git puzzles even experienced developers and is not regarded
>   as easy to use

The second paper explains the difficulties in git as "misfits" where "underlying concepts fail to meet their intended purpose" and includes an analysis of common StackOverflow questions that demonstrate these mismatches.

Comment: Nice links. I always had a gut feeling that git was less than ideal, but it's interesting to know that there's some scientific evidence confirming it.

Comment: the links are dead. here are the correct ones: https://spderosso.github.io/onward13.pdf https://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/106271

Comment: @keuleJ thank you I updated the dead links

Answer (score -21):

the major user base for SVN are large companies who are resistant to adopting new technologies, where users are less free to browse stack overflow,

compared to git, which is widely used by looser smaller companies, and just about every hobbyist on the site, who have little to no restrictions to spend time on the site

Comment: Some statistics/citation would be great! I doubt that Apple or Google are "resistant to adopting new technologies". ;)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier there is a software-engineering.SO questions on [the usage of Git over SVN](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136079/are-there-any-statistics-that-show-the-popularity-of-git-versus-svn).

Comment: @JGreenwell Interesting. Would you really say that this supports Austin's point that "the major user base for SVN are large companies who are resistant to adopting new technologies, where users are less free to browse stack overflow" however?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier absolutely they are, especially new technologies that they didn't themselves invent.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I started as a COBOL programmer in 1999 (actually started with the company in '98 as a tech and operator, but that was my first programmer job). In 2013 when finishing my first degree, I got part-time work in COBOL at a company that hadn't, and wasn't looking to, switched languages. So I would believe it but as a post I would also include some statistics which support those observations.